# C1RichTextBox in ListBox always scrolls to last list element

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, componentone, c1richtextbox

We're using the ComponentOne `C1RichTextBox` in a plain WPF `ListBox`
*(C1 WPF components V2014.3)*

Each `ListBoxItem` contains just a plain WPF `TextBlock` and a `C1RichTextBox`.

In a list with a dozen or so items - and only the first elements visible - clicking into any of the `C1RichTextBoxes` will scroll the Listbox to the last element in the list.

Clicking on any other element of the list box item won't.

We're already handling the `RequestBringIntoView` event in the `ListBoxItem` so apparently that's not the issue.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you share your code (XAML and C#) to get a better idea?

Comment: Actually the issue could not be replicated any more after upgrading to the C1 WPF components version 2015/1 - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2015v1 version can be downloaded from the following link :
http://prerelease.componentone.com/dotnet40/c1wpflibrary/2015-t1/